# Chrome IOS Screen Size Wrong

Tags: html, ios

When you open content in a new window in Chrome IOS, the innerWidth/innerHeight and clientWidth/clientHeight are returned differently.

After changing the new tab, come back and refresh or push down the window, and the value returns normally.

Is there a way to return the value normally when I open it with a new window?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>window.innerWidth + Height before setTimeout()</h1>
    <div id="w1"></div>
    <div id="h1"></div>
    <div id="w3"></div>
    <div id="h3"></div>

    <h1>window.innerWidth + Height after setTimeout()</h1>
    <div id="w2"></div>
    <div id="h2"></div>
    <div id="w4"></div>
    <div id="h4"></div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    const $ = document.getElementById.bind(document);

    const w1 = $("w1");
    const h1 = $("h1");
    const w2 = $("w2");
    const h2 = $("h2");
    const w3 = $("w3");
    const h3 = $("h3");
    const w4 = $("w4");
    const h4 = $("h4");

    function onResizeInstant() {
        w1.innerText = `w: ${window.innerWidth}`;
        h1.innerText = `h: ${window.innerHeight}`;
        w3.innerText = `w3: ${document.documentElement.clientWidth}`;
        h3.innerText = `h3: ${document.documentElement.clientHeight}`;
        window.setTimeout(onResizeTimeout, 5);
    }

    function onResizeTimeout() {
        w2.innerText = `w: ${window.innerWidth}`;
        h2.innerText = `h: ${window.innerHeight}`;
        w4.innerText = `w4: ${document.documentElement.clientWidth}`;
        h4.innerText = `h4: ${document.documentElement.clientHeight}`;
    }

    window.addEventListener("resize", onResizeInstant);

    onResizeInstant();
</script>

</html>
```

The issue was reproduced on the iPad mini5 and the iPad Air5.

I also attach a video of the issue.
[Video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gwLIcYg_wJtSidkR-JvlrBdiv8qZ3-_l/view?usp=sharing)

IOS Version: 17.3.1
Chrome IOS Version: 122.0.6261.89

Thanks in advance.